Problem with Intelephense formatting HTML/PHP in VSC
A visual representation of the problem
The problem comes when trying to use php inside of HTML.
It wants to indent the entire php code to the right to where it thinks the php code should be.
The issue is that there is no way around this issue.
failed solution 1
failed solution 2
The only solution would be to start the php in a new line, which then means that there is a lot of empty spaces inside the href:
new line
And yes I have tried simply reformatting in a new line, but the pictures show the endresult after intelephense did its thing.
Anyone have the same problem?
something like this would be ideal

Why not do the PHP stuff before the <a>, assign the results from PHP to a variable and then use <a href="<?= $variable ?>">link</a>. Nicely formats the PHP and the HTML

Thank you @brombeer
Not quite a solution to a widespread problem in my code, but works in this case.
